# Expected target size (50, 88), got torch.Size([50, 288, 88])

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to train my neuronal network. Train in the model is correct, but I can't calculate loss. The output and the target have the same dimension.

I had tried to use torch.stack, but I can't because the size of the each input is (252, x) where x is the same in the 252 elements, but is different for the others inputs.

I use a custom Dataset:

```
class MusicDataSet(Dataset):
def __init__(self, transform=None):
    self.ms, self.target, self.tam = sd.cargarDatos()  
    self.mean, self.std = self.NormalizationValues()                    
def __len__(self):
    return self.tam

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    #Normalize
    inp = (self.ms[idx]-self.mean)/self.std
    inp = torch.from_numpy(inp).float()    
    inp = inp.t()
    inp = inp.to('cuda')

    target= torch.from_numpy(self.target[idx])
    target = target.long()
    target = target.t()
    target = target.to('cuda')

    return inp, target
```

I must say that list can't be cast with something like: target = torch.Tensor() or torch.stack() because this (252, x), as I have already said.

```
def music_collate_fn(batch):
    data = [item[0] for item in batch]
    data = pad_sequence(data, batch_first=True)
    target = [item[0] for item in batch]
    target = pad_sequence(target, batch_first=True)
    return data, target


musicSet = mds.MusicDataSet()
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(musicSet,batch_size=50, collate_fn = music_collate_fn, shuffle=False)

input_dim = 252
hidden_dim = (512,1024,512)
output_dim = 88
mlp = rn.MLP(input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim).to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.RMSprop(mlp.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
for batch_idx, (x,y) in enumerate(train_loader):
    outputs = mlp(x.to(device))
    loss = criterion(outputs, y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()           
    loss.backward()                 
    optimizer.step()
```

The size of output and target is the same,

```
output: torch.Size([50, 288, 88])
target:  torch.Size([50, 288, 88])
```

But the next error apears when I try to calculate loss:

```
  File "<ipython-input-205-3c47d7aa11a4>", line 32, in <module>
    loss = criterion(outputs, y)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 904, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1970, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch
\nn\functional.py", line 1800, in nll_loss
    out_size, target.size()))

ValueError: Expected target size (50, 88), got torch.Size([50, 288, 88])
```

Comment: your question isn't clear for me but I bet you are making a confusion with your batch size when you do your training.

Comment: The input to my model is [batch_size,input, variableData]. The target has the shape [batch_size, variabledata, target]. I tried to put variableData where target, using torch.transpose(1,2), but it doesn't work.

Comment: @LeonLopez CrossEntropyLoss needs (minibatch, C) as an input, with C the number of class  classification. I need to make sure what task are you trying to do to be able to make suggestion of either (1) changing the shape or (2) changing the loss function.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using `CrossEntropyLoss` incorrectly. See the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss).

In particular, if the input is of shape [NxCxd] then target should be of shape [Nxd], and value in target are integer between 0 and C-1 i.e you can just provide the class labels and it is not required to one-hot encode the target variable. Error message also states that same.