# nn.NLLLoss() target size issue

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have a label of size [32,2,10] and I want to separate this label into label1 and label2, with which I need to compute loss against the input for each label1 and label2.

Model is VGG16 + additional classifier.

output classes = 10

```
class cust_vgg():
    def forward(self, images,model):
        out = model.features(images)
        out1 = model.avgpool(out)
        out1 = out1.reshape(out1.size(0), -1)
        return model.classifier(out1), model.classifier1(out1)  

out = cust_vgg.forward(images,model)
out_classifier,out_classifier1 = out  
labels1,labels2 = labels[0]
loss_classifier = nn.NLLLoss(out_classifier, labels1)
loss_classifier1 = nn.NLLLoss(out_classifier1,labels2)
loss = loss_classifier + loss_classifier1
loss.backward()
opt.step()
```

> Input batch_size should match with the target batch_size for
>   nn.NLLLoss()
>
> Error: Expected input batch_size (32) to match target batch_size (10).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure as I do not what the labels mean here. But I think what you want is to pick two different labels from 2nd index. Therefore you should change :

```
labels1,labels2 = labels[0]
```

to

```
labels1,labels2 = labels[:, 0], labels[:, 1]
```

Also, NLLLoss take class index as input, you do not have to use one-hot encoded labels. However, that problem has already been solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243672/expected-target-size-50-88-got-torch-size50-288-88/56250351#56250351)

Comment: iam getting this error:     multi-target not supported at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549630534704/work/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:15

Comment: @saitharun on doing what exactly?